# Apache FOP and normal XSL stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I've an xml returned from a web service.
This xml is a label used by a courier. The API specifies also the XSLT stylesheet.
I had success to produce an HTML page using XML+XSLT (i'm using Java).

I need to produce a PDF label because it must be sent to the final user.

Does exists a way to use standard XSL stylesheet instead of XSL-FO?

Does exists another solution?

Comment: XSLT can produce a plain-text file, not a PDF document. You can use XSLT to produce an XSL-FO document that can be used to generate a PDF. Another solution could be to print to PDF from your browser.

Comment: What do you mean by a "standard stylesheet"? It's possible to produce PDF by a route other than XSL-FO (e.g. via CSS paged media) but it's no more "standard" (and no easier) than the XSL-FO route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing things. [XSL-FO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) is a Markup-Language (of XML format):

> XSL-FO (XSL Formatting Objects) is a markup language for XML document formatting that is most often used to generate PDF files. XSL-FO is part of XSL (Extensible Stylesheet Language), a set of W3C technologies designed for the transformation and formatting of XML data. The other parts of XSL are XSLT and XPath. Version 1.1 of XSL-FO was published in 2006.

[XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) on the other hand is [a possibly] Turing-complete [language], making it theoretically capable of arbitrary computations [...]:

> XSLT is [...] a language for transforming XML documents into other XML documents,[1] or other formats such as HTML for web pages, plain text or XSL-FO[...]

Your question

> Does exists another solution?

can be answered with: *You are using the probably best way to handle things*.

Of course there do exist other ways to transform XML files to PDFs, but as you described your workflow, this is probably a very good approach at handling things.

If you'd like to optimize it, I would suggest to go fully XSLT (version 3.0) and reduce the Java part as much as possible.

> I need to produce a PDF label because it must be sent to the final user.

XSLT can transform your input XML to HTML and XSL-FO - and Apache FOP can output to PDF. So you are able to satisfy all of your needs with probably one XSLT file - standard conform and configurable.

So your workflow could be:

```
XML by Courier   ->    XSLT----(1)-->   HTML
                        |
                        -------(2)-->   XSL-FO  ---(FOP)--->  PDF
```